# c++ vector [-2] index returns weird value

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and just learned about vectors. I'm coming from Python, so of course I checked if I could use **negative indexing** in c++, which did not seem to work.

While trying to check if it works, I met a very weird behaviour for negative indexes in different environments.

Using negative indexes with the `.at()` function raises an error but not when using `[]` brackets.

Are these values contents of previous memory locations, or what do they represent? Is this what's called `undefined behaviour`?

Source:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> numbers = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15};
  std::cout << "Length: " << numbers.size() << "\n";
  for (int i = 4; i > -5; i--) {
    std::cout << "Pos " << i << ": " << numbers[i] << "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Length: 5
Pos 4: 15
Pos 3: 12
Pos 2: 9
Pos 1: 6
Pos 0: 3
Pos -1: 0   // other env: 201392090
Pos -2: 33  // other env: 475047512
Pos -3: 0
Pos -4: 0
```

Comment: Yes, this is what is called _undefined behavior_.

Comment: if you are coming from Python you better get used to the idea that you need to learn a new language from scratch. Pythonic C++ code won't work out well

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub -> Access out of bounds

Comment: When you put some number `pos` in bracket as index for `vector`, it essentially means `vector.begin() + pos`. Here, `vector.begin()` is the pointer to the first element of the vector. If your `pos` is negative then it's just going to show you data from some other memory location.

Comment: Also a suggestion, python indexing and c++ indexing are fairly different. Learn c++ from scratch without referring to your python knowledge. And for vector, it's better to use iterator instead of bracket index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these values contents of previous memory locations, or what do they represent? Is this what's called undefined behaviour?

No, it's not actually accessing a memory location prior to the beginning of the backing array, but one past the end:

If you use `numbers [index]`, the compiler interprets this as `numbers.operator[](index)`, i.e. the [member function `operator[]()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) is used. This function takes a parameter of type `size_t` which is an unsigned integer. The parameter `-1` is implicitly converted to a unsigned integer yields a very large number and this number is out of range of values the contract of `std::vector` covers. Read or write access to such an element is undefined behaviour. `at` in contrast to `operator[]()` does compare the parameter to the vector size guaranteeing an exception in this scenario, but with `operator[]` there's no such "safety net".

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use negative indexing in C++, not just on a container that starts at index 0.

However, you can have an iterator into the middle of a vector and index from that.

```
std::vector<int> numbers = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15};
std::vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin() + 3;
std::cout << it[-2];
```